# Se puede montar una partición en un subdirectorio del directorio /home que no está vacío en ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Tengo un sistema de supervisión en ubuntu 14.04, que guarda las imágenes en `/home/images`, hace poco se llenó la partición montada en `/home` por estas imágenes, no quiero borrarlas, entonces opté por instalar un disco duro en el equipo y crear una partición y montarla en el directorio donde se guardan las imágenes, eso si antes para que no hubiera conflictos, moví el directorio `/home/images` a la nueva partición y posteriormente la monté de forma definitiva en `/home/images`.
Aparentemente solucioné el problema pero las imágenes continúan copiándose en `/home/images/`... pero en la partición donde está montado `/home`.

¿Qué puedo hacer para que los datos se guarden en el nuevo disco duro (partición `/dev/ssd1`) sin modificar la ruta ya que no tengo la opción de cambiarla?

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev 7.9G 4.0K 7.9G 1% /dev
tmpfs 1.6G 936K 1.6G 1% /run
/dev/sda1 46G 12G 32G 28% /
none 4.0K 0 4.0K 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock
none 7.9G 76K 7.9G 1% /run/shm
none 100M 40K 100M 1% /run/user
/dev/sda3 397G 371G 26G 94% /home
/dev/sdd1 9.1T 4.0T 4.6T 47% /home/images
```

Creo que mi duda se resolvería si se responde las preguntas:

- ¿Qué pasa si monto dos particiones en el mismo directorio en linux?
- ¿En qué partición se guarda los datos?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La nueva partición necesita autorización-acceso para el usuario dueño de la carpeta.

1. Cambiar el nombre a la carpeta antigua.

   ```
    mv /home/images /home/images-old
   ```
2. Crear carpeta nueva.

   ```
    mkdir /home/images
   ```
3. Montar el disco duro (o partición) en la carpeta ya creada, habilitando acceso para el usuario actual (uid=1000).

   ```
    mount /dev/sdd1 /home/images -o uid=1000
   ```

NOTA: El comando *mount* asigna una partición a una carpeta específica (para conocer más configuraciones ejecuta `mount --help` ).

Comment: Podrías ampliar tu pregunta explicando  `mount` para los no iniciados.

Comment: Listo: he editado la respuesta agregando una descripción a cada paso, para así comprender el uso del comando **mount**

Comment: Es posible montar varias particiones en la misma carpeta, pero no sé como hacer para que se guarden los nuevos datos en la partición deseada y a veces se satura el disco duro principal. Lo he solucionado básicamente como lo describes. Necesito tener acceso a los datos de la antigua partición sin modificar la ruta, lo he solucionado moviendo los datos a la nueva partición pero estoy desaprovechando espacio de disco duro principal. Una opción sería partir la partición del disco duro principal y reducir la partición de los usuarios y sistema.